# How to find out on which partition my home dir is?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

How can I find out on which partition my `home` dir is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `df` command with the `-P` flag:

```
$ df -P /home/
Filesystem     1024-blocks     Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/sda6        913043932 90791288 775849572      11% /home
```

If `home` is not on a dedicated partition, you'll get something like:

```
$ df -P /home/
Filesystem     1024-blocks     Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/sda5         39240312 12539228  24684728      34% /
```